# Для чего нужен AccessibilityEvent?

Tags: android-sdk

Для чего нужен AccessibilityEvent?
Изучаю книгу по Android и наткнулся на такое:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Подскажите для чего нужен этот класс? За что отвечает и как им пользоваться?

Answer (score 2):

Accessibility — это доступность приложения пользователям с ограниченными возможностями (плохое зрение, слух и т.п.). Они пользуются специальными приложениями, скринридерами, которые читают вслух текст с экрана или предоставляют информацию с экрана другими способами (код Брайля, например).

Чтобы скринридеры работали, необходимо, чтобы приложения предоставляли информацию о том, что отображается на экране. Поэтому недостаточно просто нарисовать пиксели с буквами на экране, необходимо сообщить, что вы нарисовали, например, кнопку с каким-то текстом.

В примере выше контрол сообщает, что изменилась надпись. Скринридер может отловить это событие и, например, прочитать обновившийся текст.